# Duplicate records after insert statement in Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, insert, duplicates

Today i released a new application for one of my clients and something not normal happened with an INSERT statement.
During the tests we didn't face something similar and i am not sure if this happened because of lot of users access at the same time (100 users) or it is related to something else.
So after 1 insert some times it inserted 1 record in the database table some other 2-3 duplicates...I am not using transactions, is this something that could solve this problem?Below you can find my code and the one with transactions in case this would be the solution.
Thank you very much for your help!

```
$submit_the_bill = "INSERT INTO bill_status
(`bill_status_bill_id`,`bill_status_username`, `bill_status_phone_number`, `bill_status_status`,`bill_paid`, `deduction`)
VALUES ('".$bill_id."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['phone_number']."','1','0','".$deduction."')";
$submit_the_bill_result = $conn->query($submit_the_bill);

//TRANSACTION STARTS HERE
try {
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
$submit_the_bill = "INSERT INTO bill_status
(`bill_status_bill_id`,`bill_status_username`, `bill_status_phone_number`, `bill_status_status`,`bill_paid`, `deduction`)
VALUES ('".$bill_id."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['phone_number']."','1','0','".$deduction."')";
$submit_the_bill_result = $conn->query($submit_the_bill);
$conn->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
// An exception has been thrown
// We must rollback the transaction
$conn->rollback();
}
```

This is the full page, information is coming from a previous page with a form and goes to the home page after executing the query and sending the email. Any ideas?

```
<?php session_start();

require('include/config.php'); //database connection

require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$bill_id = $_POST['bill_id'];
$user_phone_number = $_POST['user_phone_number'];
$deduction = $_POST['deduction'];

$net_value_hidden = round($_POST['net_value_hidden'],2);
$official_cost_hidden = round($_POST['official_cost_hidden'],2);
$personal_cost_hidden = round($_POST['personal_cost_hidden'],2);
$tax_hidden = round($_POST['tax_hidden'],2);
$total_hidden = round($_POST['total_hidden'],2);
$total_private_price_with_vat = ($personal_cost_hidden/100)*20;
$total_private_price_with_vat = round($total_private_price_with_vat,2);
$total_payable_ammount = round($personal_cost_hidden + $total_private_price_with_vat,2);

if($total_hidden == 0) {$deduction = 4;}

if($deduction == 1) {$deduction_email = "Salary";}
else if($deduction == 2) {$deduction_email = "Cash";}
else if($deduction == 3) {$deduction_email = "Bank Transfer";}
else {$deduction_email = "No deduction";}

$submit_the_bill = "INSERT INTO bill_status
(`bill_status_bill_id`,`bill_status_username`, `bill_status_phone_number`, `bill_status_status`,`bill_paid`, `deduction`)
VALUES ('".$bill_id."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['phone_number']."','1','0','".$deduction."')";
$submit_the_bill_result = $conn->query($submit_the_bill);

$sql_smtp = "SELECT * FROM smtp_settings";
$result_smtp = $conn->query($sql_smtp);
if ($result_smtp->num_rows > 0) {   
    while($row = $result_smtp->fetch_assoc()) {
        $smtp_host = $row['smtp_server'];
        $smtp_username = $row['smtp_user_email'];
        $smtp_password = $row['smtp_user_password'];
        $smtp_ssl = $row['smtp_ssl'];
        $smtp_port = $row['smtp_port'];
    }
}
if ($smtp_ssl == 1) {$smtp_ssl = "ssl";} else {$smtp_ssl = "tls";}

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = $smtp_host;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $smtp_username;                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $smtp_password;                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = $smtp_ssl;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = $smtp_port;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('email@example.com', 'Email');
$mail->addAddress($_SESSION['username']);               // Name is optional
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $_SESSION['username']." submitted new bill - ".$_SESSION['bill_period'];
$mail->Body    = $_SESSION['username']."(".$_SESSION['phone_number'].") Submit New Bill - ".$_SESSION['bill_period']." <br/><br/>";

$mail->AltBody = $_SESSION['username']."(".$_SESSION['phone_number'].") Submit New Bill - ".$_SESSION['bill_period']." <br/><br/>";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    //echo 'E-mail sent';
}
unset($_SESSION['bill_period']);
$conn->close();

header("Location:location"); //going to the home page

?>
```

Comment: if that doesn't have an sql injection vulnerability, it's darn close.  You really should be using prepared statements to safely interpolate data into queries .

Comment: Well, why *are* you running the query twice?

Comment: I thought that was just 2 separate code examples squished together

Comment: The second is my suggestion, it is not in the code... could this solve it? Thank you for your answers , I am just trying  to find a solution

Comment: Using transactions won't stop it from inserting twice. You need to find out why it's inserting twice. Try adding a logging line to see if it's hitting the insert twice, and also check to see if you're calling that insert anywhere else.

Comment: Why don't you have a unique index preventing duplicates from being inserted in the first place? Secondly, transactions have nothing to do with preventing duplicates. Thirdly, just showing the insert statement will not help us to solve your problem. What you need to understand is why the same insert is called multiple times.

Comment: This is open to SQL injection; use a prepared statement. That's how databases get compromised/deleted.

Comment: thank you so much for your responses! i am going to share with you the rest of code, and hope we will find a solution.. i am also going to work with the prevention of sql injection but lets first find from where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I am not optimistic about transactions solving your problem.  I believe the issue is that the code is executing more than once, and if you wrap in a transaction, you'll just run 2 queries with transactions instead of 2 queries with autocommit.

Why is the code running twice?  That can't be answered with the information in your question.  We can only guess.

Likely possibility is a duplicate request to insert, either on the human end ( hitting refresh because it takes too long or because they restarted chrome and reopened tabs or because some other reason ), or on the load balancer end ( retrying failed requests ) or on an ajax call or something else.

Or, it's possible that your workflow drives multiple people to take the same action.  For example, if multiple people pull "the top bill", look at it, and then mark it complete, you need to do something in the application to make sure they don't all operate on the same records at roughly the same time.

It would be worth digging into your logs and the data rows and verifying that the number of requests to the insert web endpoint matches what you think, and the data in each "duplicate insert" is in fact exactly the same.

Your approach to fix will depend on the cause and your business logic most likely.  You could use additional tables to "check out " bill ids for particular users to make sure that the same bill doesn't get inserted twice.  You could give insert requests an ID so sending the same insert twice could be effectively deduplicated ( that last one is implemented on just about every cart checkout process in ecommerce, otherwise a refresh buys your stuff again or restarts an incomplete payment process!).